# Code not executed when variable is assigned locally

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript code as given here doesn't work when the variable `index` is assigned inside the function.
When assigned locally it only returns the 1st index from the `dialogues` array

But the code traverse through the elements in the array when the variable `index` is assigned globally.

Can you explain the reason behind this?
is it necessary to assign the variable outside the function?

```js
let board = document.getElementById("board");
let dialogues = [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6"

];


board.addEventListener("click",() => {    
    let index = 0;
    if (index < dialogues.length){
        alert(dialogues[index]);
        index++;
    }        
    else{
        index = 0;
    }            
})
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 50px;
    background-color: #2b0000;
    font-family: roboto;
}
.board {
    
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    
}

.cell{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 10px solid white;
    drop-shadow: 6px 8px 5px #fff;
    transition: 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="board" id="board">
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    </div>
    

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason is this line: `let index = 0;`

Comment: because `index` is initialized with `0` on every click.. and then the length of `dialogues` is always larger than `0`... and then `alert(dialogues[0]);`...  forever...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare your index variable inside the onclick function it will declare a new one each time you click and once the function is over, the variable will be forgotten. JavaScript variables only work on the scope you declare them, so if you declare index in a function, once the function is over it will be deleted.

Otherwise, if you declare it globally, there will be always the same varibale and it will save the values between each call to the on click function.

Hope i've helped!